# python3:How to sum column value of each three of a column

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

There is a dataframe like following:

```
 id   t_id  y1    y2
   1     1.   2.     1
   1     2.   2.     1
   1     3.   2.     1
   1     4.   2.     1
   1     .......
   1     15.   2.    1
   2     1.   2.     8
   2     2.   5.     6
   2     3.   5.     7
   2     4.   5.     5
   2     .......
   2     15.   5.   10
   ..............
```

There is a number of id (1,2...), and t_id (1,...15) for each id, there are y1, y2 for each t_id. I want to sum the y1, y2 for each id in every three t_id (123,456,789,10112,131415) like the following dataframe(I just give example)

```
   id.     t_id      y1.   y2      
   1      1,2,3      6.     3
   1.     4,5,6      6.     3
   1.     7,8,9.     6.     3
   1     10,11,12.   6.     3
   1     13,14,15.   6.     3
   ......
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can map `t_id` and groupby:

```
mapped_t_id = (df['t_id']-1)//3

(df.groupby(['id', mapped_t_id])
   .agg({'t_id':set, 'y1':'sum', 'y2':'sum'})
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to to keep the id for each row.t_id  y1  y2 like above one

Answer (score 0):

You could process the entire dataframe by grouping it by 3 rows at a time. Here's how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1]*15 + [2]*15,
                   't_id':[i for i in range(1,16)]*2,
                   'y1': [2]*15 + [5]*15,
                   'y2':[1]*15 + [i for i in range (15,0,-1)]})
print (df)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=df.columns)

for index, g in df.groupby(df.index // 3):
    df_id = g.iloc[0,0]
    df_tid = ','.join(str(g.iloc[i,1]) for i in range (3))
    df_y1 = g.sum(axis=0)['y1']
    df_y2 = g.sum(axis=0)['y2']
    df1.loc[index] = [df_id,df_tid,df_y1,df_y2]

print  (df1)
```

The output of this will be:

```
  id      t_id  y1  y2
0  1     1,2,3   6   3
1  1     4,5,6   6   3
2  1     7,8,9   6   3
3  1  10,11,12   6   3
4  1  13,14,15   6   3
5  2     1,2,3  15  42
6  2     4,5,6  15  33
7  2     7,8,9  15  24
8  2  10,11,12  15  15
9  2  13,14,15  15   6
```

While this is a good response, I do like how @Quang Hoang solved it. It is concise.